# Mathematical operations for each tag in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

There are 3 separate tags in my modal. I want to do different mathematical operations in each tag. There are 3 inputs in each tag. 2 of them to enter numbers and the other to give the result. For example, I have x + y = z problem in the first tag and I have to find the z value. In the second tag, let the formula x+y=z be the problem again, I have to enter the x and z values and find the y value.In the third tag I have to enter the y and z values in it and find the x value.My question is, I cannot write the values I need to find in 3 separate tags in a single computed?

Output:

[image]

Template:

```
           <form>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h6 class="text-dark" for="purchasePrice">x</h6>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      v-model="x"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h6 class="text-dark" for="salePrice">y</h6>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      v-model="y"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h6 class="text-dark" for="marginResult">z</h6>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      disabled
                      v-model="z"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Script

```
  data() {
    return {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
    };
  },
  computed:{
  },
```

Comment: You've just described what you've made, what is your actual question? Try to be specific.

Comment: @JesseSchoonveld Thanks for feedback.Can u check post again please?

Comment: I find your question hard to understand but am I understanding correctly that the problem right now is that on all 3 tabs they are using the same values? Like if you give the answer in the sales tab this is now the same value also being used in the purchase tab?

Comment: @JesseSchoonveld no i mean i can do a single `z()` in `compute` but I need to do the same with `y()` and `x()` so that I can find the values ​​in the other tags but it doesn't allow or I'm typing wrong